# React Native - how to make a grid of buttons

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, mobile-development

I am trying to make a screen on React Native that has a grid of images which are buttons, When an image/button is pressed, it will take the user to a different screen, and in some cloud or backend it will be saved that the user pressed on that image on that day.

How do I do all of this?? I know I should use React Native for the front end, should I use Firebase for the cloud and backend? How do I make the login for the site and save it for each user? Should I use a flatlist or scrollview? I know you can do multiple columns for a flatlist, but scrollview is better for saving states. Pls help me I need to have this application done by the end of next week and I am very, very lost.

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately your question is much too broad for SO--a question about layout shouldn't include questions about general app architecture. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to pick a layout library and make an effort, then ask us something more specific related to your attempt.

Comment: I will say that this sounds like a tall order for a short week and a half. Good luck.

Comment: You could set up a database (sql or nosql) and create an api, you can do this with nodejs or for example dotnet Core. When a picture is clicked from the front-end (React), you make a post request to the API that creates a record in the database. You can also fetch data from the database and display it in your app.